# Semantic error: The tabular operator provided to assert-schema has a different schema than expected (ADX/Kusto/KQL)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am getting the below error when running a cross-cluster join.  This query has run without error in the past (4 days ago).  Also, I have tried running:

```
.clear cache remote-schema cluster('cluster').database('db')
```

After running the above, the query still failed with the same error. About 5 mins later, the query executed without issue.

- Is this expected behavior?
- Is there a specific amount of time I should wait after running the clear cache command before retrying?

```
- Partial query failure: 0x80131500 
- message: 'Semantic error: The tabular operator provided to assert-schema has a different schema than expected.  ==> Cross-cluster query failure 
- ErrorCode=SEM0527
- ErrorReason=BadRequest
- SemanticErrors=The tabular operator provided to assert-schema has a different schema than expected.
```

Query Example:

```
cluster('cluster1')
.database('db1')
.table1
//
| join hint.strategy=shuffle kind=inner (
    cluster('cluster2')
    .database('db2')
    .table2 
    | where todatetime(Date) between ( datetime('2021-01-01')..datetime('2021-01-02') )
    | summarize hint.strategy=shuffle arg_max( Date, *) by key
) on key
```